# cursor movement through eye

Tags: c#, java

I was thinking whether it could be possible to track cursor movement through eye.
Depending on which part of screen  , the eye looks the curson will move.
Can this be achieved?
Thansks everyone for replying!.I am just looking for some new idea that can be implemented and which have not been implemented.Any ideas/suggetions are welcomed.

Comment: which eye? left or right? :)))

Comment: Yes, all kinds of experiments on this and related subjects exist. But is this a programming question? Because afaict, you cannot program the human eye... A starting point: have a webcam, install face recognition software and take a deep dive in image manipulation to find the eye and follow its movements. It'll take a few years of research...

Comment: I'm sure the military has been testing this type of human machine interface for a while now.  @ArsenMkrt:  you blink your left eye to bring up the contextual menus ;)

Comment: I believe that this has already been implemented...

Comment: Voting to close as it's not an "answerable question". However, what you're trying to do is possible but is VERY difficult, this article has plenty of links on the topic http://www.naturalnews.com/000304_3D_displays_internet_the_internet.html

Comment: Abel: Eye-tracking is hardly rocket science nowadays. No need to actually build your won eye-tracker from scratch (unless you want to reinvent the wheel, of course). But yes, it's not strictly programming-related.

Answer (score 1):

This field is called [Eye Tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_tracking).  There is a great deal of work done on this, but you do need specific hardware - at the least cameras focuessed quite tightly on the subjects eye.

Cursor movement is not useful as a method of eye tracking, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known subject in Human Computer Interface.

The idea to control the pointer with your eyes won't easily work according to me (since our eyes are always distracted by external inputs). Image you're dragging a folder with your brand new eye-mouse and a nice lady walks just outside of your window :)

Anyway, eye tracking could be useful, for example, for safety applications (you could check the eyes of a bus driver are focused on a range angle - the street - and you might want to trigger a sound alarm if he's distracting/falling asleep).

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need hardware to track this, but I'm sure it's ***possible***.  A better question would be is this ***useful***.

Think about how annoying it would be to read if the cursor kept moving along with your eyes. Even reading this text, you'd have the cursor moving along with your eyes. Personally, I would find it distracting and annoying.  ***BUT*** it is an interesting challenge, and I'm sure that there would be good applications.

Comment: At the very least, though you probably need a low-pass filter on the incoming data so that the cursor doesn't move *too* erratically. But fundamentally I agree; our eyes tend to get distracted pretty easily and if every such momentary distraction results in cursor movement (which, because of a moving object on screen probably causes more involuntarily eye movements) it's probably hard to actually point to something.

Comment: @david and @rossel:do u have any new ideas that have not been implmented and which will be useful and with some changes of success

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?  You ask a similiar question about controlling the cursor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600860/programming-touchpad-of-leaptop).  Maybe if you asked a clear question about what you want to achieve.  Right now it looks like you are just creating questions for any which way to control the cursor.

Comment: i am just tring to do some thing new and exciting